How to pass js function argument to inline c# in cshtml?
Preface:
I have a static formatting function in my backend, which takes an int Id and returns string SerialNumber. I want to keep it in on place.
In one of the Views - I am showing a column of Serial Number. This column is sortable (by sql query), so the content of the column should be Id value, so I am modifying the displayed value with js to convert Id to Serial.
So, I got this script in my .cshtml View:
<script>
    function formatToSerial(id) {
        return @MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(int.Parse(id));
    }
</script>

Problem: argument "id" is not recognized in this context.
Question: is there a nice built-in way to pass the js function argument to inline c# call? Or should I stick with duplication string formatting function separately for js?
What I did tried so far: I was looking into making the formatting JSInvokable and use it that way. But If I understood correctly - this is Blazor functionality, which I am not using in this project.

only JS or Web Assembly can run in the browser.  (Blazor is a sort of Web Assembly port of .NET... so it can seemingly call C# commands) There really isn't any "inline C# calls".

"Is there a nice built-in way to pass the JS function argument to inline C# call?" The answer to this question is no, not for Razor Pages (or a Razor View). The C# code @MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(int.Parse(id)); executes on the server when the Razor Page view is requested. The id argument in your view is a JS variable that is processed on the client. The error of the "argument id is not recognized in this context" is the result of the Razor View engine on the server trying to process the id variable that'll be evaluated by JavaScript on the client.

"Should I stick with duplication string formatting function separately for JS?" If you want to leverage your server's implementation from the client, you can make a fetch request to a Web API that returns the result from MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(). Your existing client-side function avoids the call to the server.

The comments above were transferred to an answer as Stack Overflow does not provide a way to filter questions in list views that may have answers in comments. These questions appear like they may be unaddressed in the list view. Additional content has been added to the answer.


Problem: argument "id" is not recognized in this context.

In the code sample in your question, the C# code @MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(int.Parse(id)); executes on the server when the Razor Page view is requested.
The id argument in your view is declared as a JavaScript variable that will be processed on the client through your JS function formatToSerial(id).
The error "argument id is not recognized in this context" is the result of the Razor View engine on the server trying to process the unknown/undeclared id variable the engine sees in the C# code int.Parse(id).

Question: Is there a nice built-in way to pass the JS function argument to inline C# call?

The answer to this question is no, not for Razor Pages (or a Razor View) out-of-the-box. That is, the default solution template for an ASP.NET Core Web App (Razor Pages) in Visual Studio does not provide a mechanism for JavaScript on the client to interoperate with a C# function on the server.
JavaScript/C# interoperability
There are two ways to create this interoperability in a Razor Pages project (or a MVC project) in order to leverage your server's serial formatting implementation from the client:



fetch() and a Web API
Razor Component Integration




Make a post request using the fetch() method in JavaScript with one or more id values in its payload. The URL path in the fetch() method is set to a Web API controller route.The API controller endpoint can execute MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(), return the results to the Promise methods of the fetch() method, and the Promise method can update your UI with the response results.
Integrate Razor components into your ASP.NET Razor Pages app.There are two ways to use Razor component integration that enable you to leverage your server's serial formatting implementation:1. Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in ASP.NET Core Blazor.2. Use non-routable components in pages or views.




Should I stick with duplication string formatting function separately for JS?

The solutions summarized in the table above – and expanded upon in the samples below – each come with the usual trade-offs:
Two separate functions

Maintaining two separate functions that do the same thing: one in JavaScript and the other in C#.
Any changes in one function needs to be applied and tested in the other.
Interoperability between the client and the server is not required (i.e. no HTTP requests to the server).

One function with post to Web API

Maintain one function on the server in C# that formats the id variable.
Set up a HTTP request using fetch().
Define and maintain a Web API.

One function with Razor component interop

Maintain one function on the server in C# that formats the id variable.
Integrate Razor components.
Set up a [JSInvokable] method. OR
Update your UI with Razor components.

fetch() and a Web API
fetch() sample
The following initiates a post request using the fetch() method in JavaScript with one id value in its payload.
function formatToSerial(id) {

    // For demo purposes, add multiple IDs in the 'data' array
    const data = [id, 123, 456];

    const csrfToken = document.querySelector('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').value;

    const url = "api/SerialFormat";

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'RequestVerificationToken': csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
            if (!responseData.serializedList || !Array.isArray(responseData.serializedList)) {
                document.querySelector("#web-api-result").textContent = "Empty serialized list";
                return;
            }
            let kvpConcat = "";
            const numOfEntries= responseData.serializedList.length;
            responseData.serializedList.forEach((kvp, index) => {
                const sep = index === numOfEntries -1? "": ", ";
                kvpConcat += kvp.key + "/" + kvp.value + sep;
            });
            document.querySelector("#web-api-result").textContent = kvpConcat;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

Web API sample
The Web API controller endpoint that processes the post request executes the MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial() method. The endpoint returns the results to the client and fulfills the fetch() function's Promise.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public class SerialFormatController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult Post([FromBody] List<int?> idList)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string?, string?>> kvList = [];
            foreach (int? id in idList)
            {
                kvList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>(
                    key: id?.ToString(),
                    value: MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(id))
                );
            }

            return new JsonResult(new
            {
                Success = true,
                SerializedList = kvList
            });
        }
    }
}

Razor component integration
Add a Razor component containing a method defined with the [JSInvokable] attribute in an @code{ } block. The MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial() method is executed from the [JSInvokable] method.
NOTE: If your adding the infrastructure for Razor components into your Razor Pages project, then it's assumed there are multiple instances in your project that leverage the purpose and benefits of Razor components versus the simple sample listed below.
Program.cs
Follow steps under the heading Use non-routable components in pages or views in the ASP.NET documentation to integrate Razor components into your Razor Pages project.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-non-routable-components-in-pages-or-views
using WebApplication1.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddScoped<WebApplication2.FormaterService>();

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-non-routable-components-in-pages-or-views
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-non-routable-components-in-pages-or-views
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorPages();

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/integration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-non-routable-components-in-pages-or-views
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

// Add 'endpoints.MapControllers()' to enable Web APIs
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

Components/CallDotNet.razor
Follow the steps under the heading Invoke a static .NET method.
@implements IAsyncDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference? module;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import",
                "./Components/CallDotNet.razor.js");

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("addHandlers");
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public static async Task<string?> GetFormattedSerial(string? id)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(id, out int result))
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(result));
        }

        string? message = "An ID was not entered.";
        return await Task.FromResult(message);
    }

    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (module is not null)
        {
            await module.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}

Components/CallDotNet.razor.js
// Source:
// Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in ASP.NET Core Blazor
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-8.0

export function returnArrayAsync() {
    const id = document.querySelector("#id-input").value;
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('WebApplication1', 'GetFormattedSerial', id)
        .then(data => {
            document.querySelector("#dot-net-result").textContent = data;
        });
}

export function addHandlers() {
    const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    btn.addEventListener("click", returnArrayAsync);
}

Razor view sample
@page
@using WebApplication1.Components
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}
@section Styles {
    <style>
        .result {
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    </style>
}

<h5>Use fetch() and a Web API</h5>
<input id="serial-id" type="number" />
<button id="get-serial-id">Format</button>
<p>
    <span>Result: <span class="result" id="web-api-result"></span></span>
</p>

<hr />

<h5>Call .NET method from JavaScript</h5>
<input type="number" id="id-input" />
<button id="btn">Format</button>
<p>
    Result: <span class="result" id="dot-net-result"></span>
</p>
<component type="typeof(CallDotNet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

<hr />

<h5>Razor Component UI</h5>
<component type="typeof(EmbeddedFormatSerial)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@section Scripts {
    <script src="/js/format-serial.js"></script>
}


Wow, that is a great effort, thank you!
Given that I was trying pretty hard to find a direct answer to the given questions means that it will be more than useful for the community.
And the discussion was useful as well, I learned about Blazor and Web Assembly and took into consideration if I should add it to the project (you may want to include that in your answer).
As a side note - I went to implementing duplicate of formatting function on the front end,   fetching server for it would be an overkill (performance wise as well) in my case.

You're right about taking Blazor into consideration. I've added content and code to the answer that show the integration of Razor components to leverage the C# implementation of MyFormater.GetFormatedSerial(id) from the client.
